# Titanium Javascript Runtime Error

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

```
[INFO]  Encrypting JavaScript files: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.5.1.GA ...
2016-10-29T17:37:39.849Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property 'proxyAttrs' of undefined
2016-10-29T17:37:39.864Z | ERROR  | Cannot read property 'proxyAttrs' of undefined
```

Trying to build an android app via Appcelerator Studio on Win 10. It stops building after trying to encrypt JS files. When trying to build it to a real device via Appcelerator Studio - it doesn't log the error but just stops building. Was able to see the error message after trying to build to android emulator via Titanium CLI.

UPD:

managed to get rid of this error by deactivating the google.analytics function and deleting google.analytics module.

Now though I'm getting another error. And it says that error is in file which I didn't even create and cannot find it in my project folder.

```
[ERROR] TiViewProxy: Invalid value, expected type Object.
[ERROR] D/[BNRAppListMgrReceiver]( 5902): android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED : nl.nle.annainzicht
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: (main) [803,803] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,803] - In ti:/view.js:22,8
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,803] - Message: Uncaught Error: Invalid value, expected type Object.
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,803] - Source:            _add.call(this, child);
```

My system settings are:

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
  Version                     = 10.0.14393
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 7.9GB

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.4.7
  npm Version                 = 2.15.8

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.10
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.31

Titanium SDKs
  5.5.1.GA
    Version                   = 5.5.1
    Install Location          = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.5.1.GA
    Platforms                 = android, mobileweb, windows
    git Hash                  = b18727f
    git Timestamp             = 09/27/16 05:38
    node-appc Version         = 0.2.36
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably have a call to a function that doesn't return nothing
but the view is expecting something to add.
I just had that trouble myself